# Setting the aws_region in rails/amazon web services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I've installed the aws sdk with `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.1.29'`. Upon entering the aws interactive console with `aws.rb` and trying to run commands I get the error:

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError: missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']
```

I need help on how to set the AWS_REGION environment variable. At the console I have done:

```
heroku config:set S3_REGION='us-east-1'
```

and in config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb I have tried both

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
})
```

and

```
S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  aws_region: 'us-east-1'
)
```

but to no avail. (I have set the access key id and secret access key at the console also).

Comment: should be `region: 'us-east-1'` in `Aws::S3::Client.new` as well

Comment: I've changed it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you ever get to the solution?